# Using regexp in Java to verify that a string contains a pattern

Tags: java, regex

Simple question. If I need to check if a Regexp contains a simple pattern, in my case it would be `^0039`, if I write something like this:

```
    if(Pattern.matches("^(0039|\\+39)", "00392121")) System.out.println("Yes");
    else System.out.println("No");
```

I have obviously `No` as answer because the pattern is missing the `2121`. Do I need to transform the pattern in `^(0039|\\+39).*` or is there a method more suitable for this?

I'm asking because I'm writing a method for our ETL engine and I'm not sure that everyone who's gonna use this is aware on how regexp works...so I'm foreseeing a lot of email of complaing with an obvious answer: *"append .** to your regexp"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to use the [`Matcher.find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(0039|\\+39)").matcher("00392121");

    if (m.find())
        System.out.println("Found");
}
```

*Note: This will only find the first occurrence of the pattern since it starts with `^`.*

---

Also note that [`Pattern.matches(regex, input)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) boils down to:

```
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()
```

Which calls [`Matcher.matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29). And according to the API it matches against the whole input:

> The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The `String.matches()` method returns `true` if the regex matches the *whole* String.

So yes, you have to add `.*` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case I would not use regexp but rather use String's [startsWith(String prefix, int toffset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) instead.

Especially if you're not sure that everyone who's gonna use this will be aware of how regexp works.